# Apache2 - Handling HTTP PUT

Tags: apache, xmlhttprequest, mod-perl

I have an apache2 running server working very nicely with a complex directory structure. At the end of most directories I have a perl file ('index.pl') which handles all the GET & POST commands (I need something dynamic).

Now, I want the index.pl to also handle "PUT" commands, however whenever I try sending a "PUT" command, I get 405. If I enable DAV, the PUT command does not execute the perl script but rather just puts the file in the directory.

Now, I know this is not the common use for the PUT command - the thing is that I'm writing a backup server for a very complex webservice which handles the PUT commands (and as such, I need to too).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your index.pl file you need to do:

```
$method = $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD};
$data = '';
$buffer = '';
if ( $method eq 'PUT' ) {
  sysread(STDIN, $data, $length);
  while( length($data) < $length ) {
      last unless sysread(STDIN, $buffer, 4096);
      $data .= $buffer;
  }
  # You now have your PUT data in the $data variable.
}
```